# Al invertir una lista solo obtengo el primer elemento

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

En esta función quiero invertir esta lista `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
He usado el bucle `for`, pero a la hora de imprimir me sale `[5]`, ¿por qué? ¿Qué he hecho de mal? Les comparto el código.

```
def invertir_lista (num):
    
    lista_invertida = []
    
    for i in range(len(num)-1,-1,-1):
        
        lista_invertida.append(num[i])
        
        # Devolver la lista invertida
        
        return lista_invertida
    
lista_original = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista_invertida = invertir_lista(lista_original)

print(lista_invertida)
```

Answer (score 3):

Comprobando tu código, creo que te sobraba una tabulación en el return:

```
def invertir_lista(num):
    lista_invertida = []

    for i in range(len(num)-1,-1,-1):       
        lista_invertida.append(num[i])

    return lista_invertida

lista_original = [1,2,3,4,5] 
lista_invertida = invertir_lista(lista_original)

print(lista_invertida)
```

Cuando puedas, pruébalo y nos dices si cumple con el objetivo

Comment: ohhh tienes toda la razon!!!! muchas gracias amigo. Corre perfecto ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo Jose en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/592317/306873), el error está en la indentación del `return`, que hace que la función termine al final de
la primera iteración del bucle, devolviendo una lista que contiene solo un elemento (el último de la lista original).

Otra solución más eficiente, usando *slicing*:

```
lista_original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lista_invertida = lista_original[::-1]

print(lista_invertida) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Muy buena esta también gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con las respuestas anteriores.
Así y todo, aunque no me guste memorizar métodos, existe el método `reverse` que te permite hacer directamente el cálculo.

```
lista_original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lista_invertida = lista_original.copy() #copio la lista
lista_invertida.reverse() #invierto la lista
print(lista_invertida) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```